# Rayleigh Quotient

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces

Assume a projector matrix $\mathbf{P} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$, which is of rank $m$ (i.e. $N - m$ linearly independent vectors could null $\mathbf{P}$) and an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1}$. Consider the Rayleigh quotient:

\begin{equation}
f(N)  = \frac{\mathbf{x}^{H} \mathbf{P} \mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^{H} \mathbf{x}}
\end{equation}

Is it right to say the following: "$f(N) \rightarrow 0$ as $N \rightarrow + \infty$ for fixed $m$" ?
And if so, is there anything related to this statement ? Any formal way of justifying ?

I have a feeling that the structure of $\mathbf{x}$ should be included in order to say something about the previous statement. Obviously this is not true if $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{P}\mathbf{z}$ for any $\mathbf{z}$.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

First of all, without loss of generality we can assume $\|x\|=1$, since rescaling $x$ to be of length 1 does not change the value of the fraction. As you pointed out, for vectors of the form $x=Pz$ for some $z$ the statement does nto hold. On the other side, for vectors $x \in \text{Ker}(P)$ the statement obviously holds. Hence the question stands:

With $N \rightarrow \infty$, how does $x$ changes? Are we adding zeros at each $N\rightarrow N+1$ or ones or..? More importantly, how does the decomposition of $x$ into $x=x_{\text{Ker}(P)}+x_{\text{Im}(P)}$ changes?

Indeed, this is the additional structure you need to give, to get an answer. In other words, the angle of the $\text{Ker}(P)$ and $x$ should be imho specified.